# Current User is LocalSystem Check?

Tags: security, impersonation, windows-identity, iprincipal

It is easy enough to determine if the user running my C# .NET 4.0 console app is a member of the local Administrators group. I am also trying to determine if it is running under LocalSystem. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.IsWellKnown(WellKnownSidType.LocalSystemSid)
```